# How to Get and Update Characteristic of Beacon in Android

Tags: android, ibeacon

I have created App that Update Beacon Characteristic like UUID, Major ,Minor ,Tx power and Broadcast Interval.
But now i want to create same functionality in Android,

I have checked Many tutorial and Link form GitHub, But not got use full resource.
Although Find good library that can be used to ranging and monitoring,
[AltBeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon)

Can someone please guide me to any resource for this functionality

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that there is no standard way to configure Bluetooth characteristics on beacons.  Some beacon manufacturers don't even build bluetooth configurability into their devices -- they either have fixed identifiers or identifiers that must be changed over a USB connection or through a shell script.

If you are working with a specific beacon model that does offer configurability through Bluetooth characteristics, the solution to doing this will be specific to that manufacturer and model.  Every manufacturer and model would require a different solution.  For this reason, the Android Beacon Library you mention does not offer configurability as a feature.

Comment: Thanx for answer, Make sense. But yes my Beacon manufacturer did provide support to update characteristic, As i am doing same in iOS. but i am not getting way to do that in android.